# how to put links to the layout made using photoshop in dreamweaver

Tags: css, dreamweaver, photoshop

I'm just curious how do they put links on the website layouts in photoshop using dreamweaver.
How do they do that?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense... you'll have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: are you talking about 'hot-spots' that you can draw using 'design mode' in dreamweaver?

Comment: yeah, I've red it already. I have to put the pieces all together like a jigsaw puzzle using dreamweaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to set links on some parts/areas of an image, you should use `imagemap` here is an simple example:

```
  <img src="image.png" width="345" height="312" border="0" alt="this is my image" usemap="#mymap">
  <map name="mymap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="11,10,59,29" href="http://www.koblenz.de/" alt="Koblenz" title="Koblenz">
    <area shape="rect" coords="42,36,96,57" href="http://www.wiesbaden.de/" alt="Wiesbaden" title="Wiesbaden">
  </map>
```

you can define different shapes for the clickable areas like rectangle, circles and polygons - just ask google for the exact syntax. note the `usemap`-attribute of the image to define wich map should be used.

EDIT: i think i misunderstood your question - but maybe this helps anyway...